# VB.Net with Oracle ODP.net transaction with read_committed isolation returns original values after first call

Tags: vb.net, oracle, transactions, odp.net, isolation-level

I have set up a Transaction with isolation level READ_COMMITTED using VB.net and Oracle ODP.net

> Dim OraTransaction As OracleTransaction =
>   oraConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

It is declared within a Function block and right after, a FOR loop runs with several Sub calls inside passing the Connection object's reference. During the execution a Select is issued and two fields from that Table change.

The very first iteration, the Select command, using a DataAdapter object, returns the stored values as expected. During the execution the values of the fields change and then I use a Command object to execute an update, but not commit yet.

When the second iteration issues the aforementioned Select, instead of the updated values, the query still returns the original values.

Thank for any help.

J.

Comment: With ReadCommitted, "dirty reads" are not allowed, so only committed data will be shown. It sounds like it's doing exactly what it's supposed to, unless I'm misunderstanding your issue... AskTom has a great article on this that I reference a lot, his quote on Read-Committed "Oracle Database will reconstruct the modified data as it appeared when the query began, returning the answer that was in the database when the query started." You should read more of [the article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o65asktom-082389.html) and see what isolation level suits your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for another way to persist the changes, I found out that there was an error in the Select query I was using to pull data from the Table.

If I execute an Update command to the Table and then execute a Select command, it actually returns the updated values. When manually throwing an exception before the Transaction completes, all the changes at that point are rolled back and when the Transaction completes, it successfully commit the changes, which is exactly what I wanted to achieve.